# Drawing vector graphics on iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Please forgive the newbie question.  I have an iphone game that currently uses lots of png images for animations.  While this works well, the images are taking up alot of memory.  I have the images in a vector format as well and I would prefer to use those instead of the pngs.

Is there a native way to do that?

Comment: Did you get answer to your question.
i also need to draw SVG in iphone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to use Core Animation, right? In that case your options are pretty limited. There are several classes of layers which display graphics: CALayer draws a bitmap, CAShapeLayer draws a bezier path, CAGradientLayer draws a linear gradient, CATextLayer draws text. You can also use OpenGL with CAEAGLLayer, but it doesn't mix with other Quartz graphics very well performance-wise. Most likely, you will have to use PNGs anyway because even if you have PDFs which you can display via Core Graphics, they will have to be rasterized before you can show them in a CALayer. Moreover, the rasterization will be done on the CPU, which you don't want to be happening with each animation frame.

With regard to memory usage, I feel your pain. A lot of images == a lot of memory. Core Animation is not exactly a gaming engine, it is designed with UI animation in mind. I once did an iPhone game with CA and besides memory usage there were performance problems too when too many animations took place simultaneously. Have a look at Cocos2D, it is much better suited for games and is being actively developed. Granted, it has issues of its own, it deserves mentioning as an option.

Comment: This was a while ago, but cocos2d is what I ended up with eventually. I recommend it to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate?

- [iphone-development-svg-image-in-uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326709/iphone-development-svg-image-in-uiwebview)
- [svg-images-in-an-iphone-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251029/svg-images-in-an-iphone-application)

EDIT:

Have you read through the [Quartz2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)?  By "vector images" I'm not sure what format you mean.  I assume you mean SVG.  If you really can't use a `UIWebView` for this, then Quartz2D is probably the way I would do the custom rendering.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  I need to manipulate the images more than a uiwebview will allow.  Draw to layers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might find more information in a couple of GitHub projects that come under Objective-C and SVG.

https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=objective-c&q=SVG